# Conditional filtering based on a specified value or unspecified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to run a SQL query that will filter either to a value passed in a parameter, or if the value in the parameter is 'Unspecified' then all values should be returned.

The parameter is `@station` which may contain the values `'Unspecified', 'Station1', 'Station2', 'Station3'` etc.

If the parameter `@station` is equal to `Station1` for example, I want the returned data to be filtered to only `'Station1'`, however if the parameter `@station` is equal to `'Unspecified'` then the returned data should include values for `station1, station2` and all stations.

I am using other filters as part of this query, here is my code below and it is the last line that doesn't work:

```
where tblRTC.CODE IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')
and CAST(tblDET.START_DATE AS Date) >= CAST (@start_date AS Date)
and CAST(tblDET.END_DATE AS Date) <= CAST (@end_date AS Date)
and IIF(@station = 'Unspecified',tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION <>@station,tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION = @station)
```

I am writing this in a 3rd party application and have no control over the parameters passed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The reason your statement failed is that `IIF` is not an SQL function.

Comment: @SchmitzIT What do you mean? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: @gotqn Wow. I never knew that, lol. Thought it was MS Access only.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Note, it is available in SQL Server 2012 +

Comment: @gotqn That explains it. I have to admit that I am not quite up-to-date with all changes to T-SQL over the years (even though I should be). Thanks for educating me :) Always happy to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where tblRTC.CODE IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')
and CAST(tblDET.START_DATE AS Date) >= CAST (@start_date AS Date)
and CAST(tblDET.END_DATE AS Date) <= CAST (@end_date AS Date)
and tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION = (case when @station  not in( 'Unspecified') then @station else tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION end)
```

Comment: I used the above code and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps

```
where tblRTC.CODE IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')
and CAST(tblDET.START_DATE AS Date) >= CAST (@start_date AS Date)
and CAST(tblDET.END_DATE AS Date) <= CAST (@end_date AS Date)
and tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION = (case when @station <> 'Unspecified' then @station else tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
where tblRTC.CODE IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')
and CAST(tblDET.START_DATE AS Date) >= CAST (@start_date AS Date)
and CAST(tblDET.END_DATE AS Date) <= CAST (@end_date AS Date)
and 
(
    @station = 'Unspecified'
    OR
    tblSTACON.DESCRIPTION = @station
)
```

If `@station = 'Unspecified'` it will return all records, if it has different value it will filter by it.